# SSRS 2013 Heat Map

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, heatmap

Software: MS Visual Studio Shell 2013

I am currently working on a matrix heat map for an SSRS Report that I am trying to publish.

The textbox I am trying to apply the background to is grouped in by a row and column. It has a count function to determine the value of that cell.

Report Code I am using is:

```
public const ColorScaleRed = "#FF0000"
public const ColorScalePink= "#ff6666"

public function ColorScaleWPR(value, minValue, maxValue) as string

    ColorScaleWPR = ColorScale3(value, _
        minValue, "White", _
        ColorScalePink, _
        maxValue, ColorScaleRed)

end function

public function ColorScale3(value as object, minValue as object, minColor as string, midColor as string, maxValue as object, maxColor as string) as string

    ' Use average of minValue and maxValue as midValue
    dim midValue as object
    if IsNumeric(minValue) and IsNumeric(maxValue) then
        midValue = (CDbl(minValue) + CDbl(maxValue)) / 2
    end if

    ColorScale3 = ColorScale3(value, _
        minValue, minColor, _
        midValue, midColor, _
        maxValue, maxColor)

end function

public function ColorScale3(value as object, minValue as object, minColor as string, midValue as object, midColor as string, maxValue as object, maxColor as string) as string

    if IsNumeric(value) and IsNumeric(midValue) and CDbl(value) < CDbl(midValue) then
        ColorScale3 = ColorScale(value, minValue, minColor, midValue, midColor)
    else
        ColorScale3 = ColorScale(value, midValue, midColor, maxValue, maxColor)
    end if

end function

public function ColorScale(value as object, minValue as object, minColor as string, maxValue as object, maxColor as string, optional errorColor as string = "Transparent") as string

    ColorScale = errorColor

    if not IsNumeric(value) or not IsNumeric(minValue) or not IsNumeric(maxValue) then
        exit function
    end if

    ' Do all calculations using doubles (can't mix doubles and decimals)
    value = CDbl(value)
    minValue = CDbl(minValue)
    maxValue = CDbl(maxValue)

    if minValue >= maxValue then
        exit function
    end if

    if value <= minValue then
        ColorScale = minColor
        exit function
    end if
    if value >= maxValue then
        ColorScale = maxColor
        exit function
    end if

    dim scaleValue, r, g, b as double
    dim minRGB, minR, minG, minB as integer
    dim maxRGB, maxR, maxG, maxB as integer

    scaleValue = (value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)

    minRGB = GetRGB(minColor)
    minR = minRGB / 2^16
    minG = (minRGB mod 2^16) / 2^8
    minB = minRGB mod 2^8

    maxRGB = GetRGB(maxColor)
    maxR = maxRGB / 2^16
    maxG = (maxRGB mod 2^16) / 2^8
    maxB = maxRGB mod 2^8

    r = minR + ((maxR - minR) * scaleValue)
    g = minG + ((maxG - minG) * scaleValue)
    b = minB + ((maxB - minB) * scaleValue)

    ColorScale = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", _
        CInt(Math.Floor(r)), _
        CInt(Math.Floor(g)), _
        CInt(Math.Floor(b)))

end function

private function GetRGB(colorStr as string) as integer

    GetRGB = 0

    if colorStr.StartsWith("#") then
        GetRGB = Int32.Parse(colorStr.Substring(1), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        exit function
    end if

    dim c as System.Drawing.Color
    c = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colorStr)

    GetRGB = (c.R * 2^16) + (c.G * 2^8) + c.B

end function
```

My problem is when i set the background expression.

I am able to get the heat map to properly render using the following expression:

```
=Code.ColorScaleWPR(Count(Fields!Candidate_ID.Value),0,10)
```

However, I don't want to use static values for the min and max values. I want them to be dynamic because depending on the parameters chosen those min and max values could vary widely.

So I used the following code

```
=Code.ColorScaleWPR(Count(Fields!Candidate_ID.Value), Min(Fields!Candidate_ID.Value,"DataSet1"), Max(Fields!Candidate_ID.Value,"DataSet1"))
```

When I run the report it renders completely white and none of the conditioning is applied to the cells.

Any suggestions to make it dynamic would be awesome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that RS is able to calculate all groupings upfront then find min/max from them to apply color scale.
 The best approach to try, is to calculate min and max values for every group into separate Dataset from the original Dataset query. Then pull needed values based on matching group criteria using expression. I would go that direction... 
PS. I did not have enough time to make that beast alive for my case when I am using color scale on pivoted matrix groupings:)